# How do you specify git URLs with spaces on Windows under cygwin?

Tags: git, url, cygwin, whitespace, filenames

If I have a git repository under cygwin with a directory name of the form /cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/user/My Documents/My Dropbox/xxxxx how do I construct a file: URL for git that references this repository?

Answer (score 6):

I don't have a Windows machine around to test it out, but you should be able to quote the whole path with double quotes, or alternately escape all spaces with a backslash.

If that doesn't work, try making a symlink that doesn't have spaces and reference the symlink from git.